# Can we remove a process builder component from a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, process-builder

We accidently added in a process builder into our managed package and i cant see a way to remove it. I cant even upload a deactivated process so that the process doesnt run by default.

Any thoughts on how we can remove a process from the package?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the ISV Guide ,It is not developer deletable .Hence I suspect you wont be able to remove it .You can just deactivate it .

While it is Subscriber deletable meaning your end users can delete it .

Here is the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) link

Comment: Yeah i read through the doc and was hoping against hope someone might have a workaround. This becomes a restriction because now i cant get my app to be prof edition ready which is a sad :(

Comment: Always use git or any source control system ,so that any issues like this ,you can deploy to another org and regenerate managed package.One of many lessons learned