# Remove Components (Process builder) From Managed released package

Tags: trigger, managed-package, process-builder, package-install

I have a situation. One of Our client is using Professional edition. But our managed release package has a Process builder with APEX invocableMethod in it. Professional Edition will not allow any Apex related flows/process builders etc.. Workaround will be using a traditional Trigger. However, I am unable to remove already existing Process Builder from the package so that I can insert the Trigger and install it on Client Profession Edition. 
Please let me know what are the steps to be taken to remove Components from managed package. 
Thank you.

THIS IS THE ERROR THAT I AM GETTING While installing the package in professional edition with Process Builder *action type* set to APEX.

> "myRule_1_A1 (Action Call) - We can't find an action with the name and
>   action type that you specified."

Comment: That's really odd. I believe when a managed package installs an InvocableMethod, the subscriber can invoke it even in Professional Edition (e.g. the DLRS plugin can do this when you set a rollup's invocation method to Process Builder). Strange that the package can't install such a reference itself.

Comment: I forgot to include the error/exception that I am getting while installing the package in professional edition @CharlesT . I have updated the Question. If I can do something in Professional Edition (Client org) to get it installed, please let me know. I'll be in your debt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot delete a process builder from a managed package. But you can de-activate it. Event though [Can we remove a process builder component from a managed package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119861/can-we-remove-a-process-builder-component-from-a-managed-package) is 2 years old it's still relevant to date. Below is from the latest [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm).

> In a development organization, you can’t [delete](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_deploy_package.htm&type=5) a flow or flow version
>   after you upload it to a released or beta managed package.

**Note: Updating based on @charlesT comments**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can we deprecate it like Apex Global classes?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Honestly not sure about it!

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure if the "Process" entry in that table is Process Builder or Approval Process. My instinct would be to go by the "Flow" entry which says "Upgradeable: Yes, Subscriber Deletable: Yes, Developer Deletable: No, Protectable: No, IP Protection: No"

Comment: @CharlesT Actually I suspect you might be true!

Comment: Yeah I really don't know, I guess you'd have to experiment with a dummy package and report back. Personally I would not be comfortable releasing a managed package with a Process Builder in it. Either the logic is internal (and if the customer needs to be able to turn it off, provide a custom setting or such), or you give the customer an Invocable Process and let them create the PB and decide when to create it and turn it on/off.

Comment: @CharlesT Good catch actually thanks for pointing out!

Comment: What @CharlesT said is correct. That's what I did about the invocable PB. But the problem is with the Professional edition. It is not allowing to install a package with invocable PB in it. If PB is not a Developer Deletable, is that can be done by raising a support ticket to salesforce? Or I have to stuck with this config and I have just ruined our env??

Comment: If it's Developer Upgradeable, will it let you publish a newer version of the PB into the package displacing the old one? That would remove the dependency.

Comment: Yes it Will. However, please note that the PB has action type set to 'APEX' and calling an apex class to make outbound calls. Even if I upgrade the PB, action type is faded and set to APEX fixed. Unable to change it. This option is not there in Professional edition as that is one of limitation. So To be frank, it is not about invocale PB. It is about choosing type to APEX.